# Any info on unstable GROUP permissions when sending another user a modifiable box with a no-mod script inside it?

Tags: permissions, linden-scripting-language

I am trying to send a modifiable box with a no-mod script inside it to another user and cannot get  the hoped for result. What I was hoping for is that the recipient could modify the box but not the script.  Sadly that is not what happens.

What happens is that the user receives the box, and upon opening it, it shows the MOD box checked, and even says "You can modify this object". Good. And, indeed,  the user can change the texture of the box, save it to inventory, re-rez it and the texture survives unchanged.   Still good.

BUT,  when the user changes the GROUP the box belongs to,   with the box rezzed,  they can do it and it seems to work.   But as soon as they take the box back into inventory three things happen.
(1) where it used to say, in inventory (no copy) it now says (no copy) (no modify) and
(2) when they rez it again,   the GROUP reverts to what it was when I sent out the  box, and 
(3) curiously, the texture does not revert.

I looked for any further posts here regarding permissions.

I found and  read with interest an Oct 14 thread:  [Modify permissions changed when sending items in a box](https://community.secondlife.com/forums/topic/444177-modify-permissions-changed-when-sending-items-in-a-box/) in the Second Life Community Forum.

Of course I found the overall result of that problem to be basically:  "Second Life does that sometimes".

I imagine this is relatively easy for someone else to replicate on some different sim, with
different avatars and different box, on a different day if any of that changes things.

Advice?   Links to the best place on-line to read up on permissions?

Links to other discussion forums where I might find assistance such as StackOverflow?

Thank you.

Afterthought #1 -- Yes I did set modify BOTH with the box Rezzed and with it in inventory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permissions shown in inventory are the most restrictive permissions on the object *and its contents*. The object is still modifiable but the inventory listing will show no modify if a script inside the object is no modify.

The group is set to the active group of the person rezzing it (or, in viewers with "rez under land group" enabled, the land group, should the person rezzing it be a member). Groups are not stored when the object is taken back into your inventory; it has nothing to do with the group you set it to.

Comment: Alex, thank you.  This is a total surprise to me that "Groups are not stored when the object is taken back into your inventory". It certainly explains what i saw.  That pretty much derails my reading the object's group to set a group-specific drop-box -- I guess I wlll have to go with a note-card driven solution after all.